# How to access parent auth status in array

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm not sure whether the title of this is appropriate as I'm  new to Firebase Authentication and rules, however, I have successfully setup authentication and am now trying to protect a particular route and can't seem to access the relevant data, here's my Firebase rules on my realtime database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "accounts": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "demo": {
      ".read": "accounts.$uid === auth.uid",
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to access the accounts/$uid/ from within "demo", it doesn't seem to work, what am I missing/what do I need to change?

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

The code in question not working is:

```
".read": "accounts.$uid === auth.uid"
```

I can't seem to access this part. It doesn't seem to get the current user's authentication status.

**UPDATE**

See attached screenshot for my attempt on using a predefined variable. I'm simply trying to get the auth status and I'm getting an error saying it's undefined?

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that is not working against these rules?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Absolutely, just updated

Comment: That's not what I meant. You say "it doesn't seem to work", and I'd like to see *what* "it" is here. Most likely that is some code from your application.

Comment: It doesn't seem to get the current user's authentication status

Comment: That could happen if you attach the listener before the user is authenticated. But it's hard to be sure without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to protect here?  What's the requirement, in plain English?  As Frank said, showing client code is also helpful.  But mostly I just don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: FYI if you're trying to read some other location in the database, you need to be using one of the [predefined variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#predefined_variables) that let you build a path to that location.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've tried using a predefined variable, as you can see I'm trying to get the $uid from Accounts, but it's not liking it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm using a GET request from Firebase in my application - Nuxt JS. See attached screenshot above

Comment: You can only use a `$` variable under the node where you declare, pretty similarly to the scoping rules of variables in programming languages. What do you want that `child($uid)` that is raising the error to accomplish?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I want it to get the User ID of the registered account, e.g: `/accounts/myuniqueIDforaccount/`

Comment: The UID of the current user who is trying to access the data is available in `auth.uid`. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. But if you're trying to ensure that a read of quotes is only allowed if the user has a document in the `accounts` node, you're looking for `exists()`.

Answer (score 0):

The UID of the current user who is trying to access the data is available in `auth.uid`. If you're trying to ensure that a read of quotes is only allowed if the user has a document in the `accounts` node, you're looking for [`exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#exists).

```
"website-quotes": {
  ".read": "root.child('accounts').child(auth.uid).exists()"
}
```